# Passing string variable to the Postgres LIKE query

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

In my flask app I am trying to pass a string to the query below:

```
tag = "Abcd"

conn = get_db_connection()
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM database WHERE message LIKE %s ESCAPE ''", (tag,))
data = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

I receive blank result.

I use psycopg2. My Postgres database has message containing `"Abcd"` and it works fine if I simply do:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM database WHERE message LIKE '%Abcd%'")
```

If I try to pass it as a variable `"tag"` is my syntax for `LIKE` query correct?

Comment: You must add the percent signs then: `tag = "%Abcd%"`.

Comment: `LIKE '%%'||%s||'%%'`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `%` in your tag.

Try this:

```
tag = '%Abcd%' #--->> change here, add %Abcd%

conn = get_db_connection()
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM database WHERE message LIKE %s ESCAPE ''", (tag,))
data = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```